# Why isn't the state being passed down to child here (TypeScript/React/SPFX)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

In this example I have a Parent class component: Dibf.
I have a Child class component: Header.

I can manage to pass props from Parent down to child. But I'm trying to pass state down by doing this (bottom line of the below code chunk):

```
export interface IDibfState {

    CurrentUserTitle: string;
    CurrentUser: string[];
    CurrentUserGroups: string;
    CurrentUserID: string[];
    CurrentUserEmail: string;
    FullName: string;
    UniId: string;
    FilteredItems: IDibfItems[];
    Author: string;
    CurrentUserRole: string;
    Items: IDibfItems[];
    DepartmentsList: IDropdownOption[];
    SelectedDept: string;
    Id: number;
    JobRef: string;
    FormStatus: string;
    Title: string;
    JobTitle: string;
    Date: Date;
    DateOfDiscovery: Date;
    IncidentDetails: string;
    PersonalData: string;
    PhoneNo: string;
    Department: string;
    SubDepartment: string;
    LoggedInUser: string;
    LoggedInUserPPDefaultItems: string[];
}


export interface IDibfProps {
  description: string;
  context: WebPartContext;

}

export default class Dibf extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      CurrentUserTitle: null,
      CurrentUser: null,
      CurrentUserGroups: null,
      CurrentUserID: null,
      CurrentUserEmail: null,
      FullName: null,
      UniId: null,
      FilteredItems: [],
      Author: null,
      CurrentUserRole: null,
      Items: [],
      DepartmentsList: [],
      SelectedDept: undefined,
      Id: null,
      JobRef: null,
      Title: null,
      JobTitle: null,
      Date: null,
      DateOfDiscovery: null,
      IncidentDetails: null,
      PersonalData: null,
      FormStatus: null,     
      PhoneNo: null,
      Department: null,
      SubDepartment: null,
      LoggedInUser: null,
      LoggedInUserPPDefaultItems: [],

    };

    // this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this._getDepartments = this._getDepartments.bind(this);
    this._getUser = this._getUser.bind(this);
  }

  // public handler(event) {
  //   this.setState({
  //     value: event.target.value
  //   });
  // }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IDibfProps> {
    return (
      <Router>

        <div className={ styles.dataForm }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>  
          <Label style={{fontSize: '50px'} }> Data Form</Label>    
          <Header usertitle={this.state.CurrentUserTitle}/>
```

As you can see I've provided the two interfaces necessary for TypeScript. State and Props. You can also see I'm trying to pass the CurrentUserTitle state to the  child component. Which is here:

```
export class Header extends React.Component<any, {}> {

  public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
    return (


          <div>
              <Label>Hello {this.props.usertitle}</Label>

          <div className={styles.row}>   
              <DefaultButton className={styles.clearButton}
                disabled={false}
                checked={true}
                text="Clear Form"
                onClick={this.props.handler}
              />
```

As you can see the `React.Component<any, {}>` is set to `any` for props, which allows me to avoid an error message if I set it to `{}` which it originally was. 
Unfortunately nothing shows in the  component.

If it helps, the error that shows if I put `React.Component<{}, {}>` for the  component is:

'Property usertitle does not exist on type ReadOnly{ children?: ReactNode; }> & ReadOnly<{}>'

Can anyone tell me how I can pass this state down to the Header component so it can be update then sent back up? If this is the correct way to do things.

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Dibf` class, you need to pass the `handler` method as a property to the `Header` component:

```
<Header usertitle={this.state.CurrentUserTitle} handler={this.handler.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'Object doesn't support property or method 'setState'' when clicking the button. Note the button is on the child component and it sets the state (the state being in the parent). I'm guessing that the handler function isn't enough to set all those states?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the state from the children component to the parent component . Then you need to pass a function as a prop from the parent component to children component and call that in the child component.

The reason you are seeing the error if you remove 'any' is that , the Header component is receiving a prop , which typescript was not able to recognise. Providing State and Props in the interface will helps you in strict type checking where we are explicitly telling that the component should have only this props and state.

```
interface HeaderProps
{
 usertitle:string
}

export class Header extends React.Component<HeaderProps>
```

Example for incrementing the state in the parent component by child component . https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-pine-w63m0